# Auto-layout - StackView deleting existing constraints

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, interface-builder, xcode8

I'm hardly learning to implement some iOS app screens in xCode Interface Builder with auto-layout.

I've already placed some elements with working constraints but I realize it would be more practical to group them into a vertical `StackView`.

At first it seems pretty easy as I did it for a previous screen. However, once I embed my elements in the StackView, all my margins constraints are gone ! Also, if I try to manually put back my constraints, they don't work at all and generate ambiguity.

I don't fully understand the way iOS UI builder works, so I'd gladly need some help.

See screenshots below.

[image: Working constraints]

[image: All constraints are gone!]

Comment: What do you mean by "margin constraints"? Do you mean vertical constraints to put space between the stacked views? Or are you talking about constraints between the inner views and the top-level view's margins?

Comment: Both, as depicted in screenshots.

Comment: Spend a little time trying out the different characteristics of the stack view - `Alignment`, `Distribution`, and, particularly, `Spacing`. That may give you just what you want.

Comment: Thanks ! Just found out 5min before your comment. The distribution was the problem. You can post it as an answer so I can check it as closed. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constraints inside stack views can be quirky, but playing around with / experimenting with the characteristics can help.

In particular, adjusting `Alignment`, `Distribution`, and `Spacing` can often do the trick.